# Get Image in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, image

How many ways to get an image in Magento!

Anyway, I'm trying to get an image. I'm in a foreach loop like this:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $key=>$item): ?>
```

Product details are getting displayed like this:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($item->getProductSku()) ?>
```

But I can't seem to get the image to show and I've many ways.

How can I get the image to show?

Comment: Where and what image you want to display in foreach loop?Can you give me more details about this

Comment: At this point any image will do : ) But preferably the thumbnail.  It's in the customer account page. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Product images are typically rendered using the `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image` class in the following way:

1. Create an instance of the helper image class: `$imageHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/image');`
2. Provide the instance with the product and image attribute code that you want to render: `$imageHelper->init($product, $imageAttributeCode);`
3. Specify width and height to which the image should be resized: `$imageHelper->resize($width, $height);`
4. Call `$imageHelper->__toString()` to generate the image in `media/catalog/product/cache` (it it doesn't already exist) and return an url to it. When calling this method in a phtml, you can just use `<?php echo $imageHelper ?>`, which automatically triggers the `__toString` method.

In most cases, the above steps are executed inline:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, $imageAttributeCode)->resize($width, $height) ?>
```

So for the case of rendering a 75x75 thumbnail of the products shown on the sales order view page, you can add the following to a template override of `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml`:

```
<img
    src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_item->getProduct(), 'thumbnail')->resize(75, 75) ?>"
    width="75"
    height="75"
    alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"
/>
```